# spotify api no token provided, error 401, getting artists from httparty

Tags: api, spotify, httparty

I have trouble when I tried to get response from my follow artists on spotify api.

I am using with httparty for that:

```
HTTParty.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, query: { 'client_id' => 'my_client_id', 'client_secret' => 'my_client_secret', 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://0.0.0.0:8080', 'scope' => 'user-follow-read' })
```

After that, I proceed with:

```
HTTParty.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist', headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, query: {'Authorization' => 'Bearer my_access_token' })
```

Then I got this return:

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x3e7dc38 parsed_response={"error"=>{"status"=>401, "message"=>"No token provided"}}, @response=#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>
```

I know that something is wrong, but I don't understand  what. Someone can help me?

Comment: Hi, it seems to indicate you're not passing a token. Are you certain you're passing the token in place of `my_access_token` ? Does your first call return `access_token` successfully?

Comment: Yes, I am. I couldn't get a successful return yet.

Comment: any luck? did you succeed?